# Elliptical orbit and circular motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

What I've learned from the textbook is that when a satellite orbits in a ellipse, the source of gravity (planet) will be placed at one of the foci. Now, the question is can we analyse this using circular motion? And why is ellptical orbit often favoured opposed to circular motion?

Comment: "*when a satellite orbits in a ellipse, the source of gravity (planet) will be placed at one of the foci.*" I thought it was the center of mass of the two bodies that was at the focus

Answer (score 1):

Any ellipsis has two focal points (foci). For circular motion, such as a satellite in a perfectly circular orbit, these two points coincide and we instread call it the centre.

Elliptic orbits are "favoured", so to say, in theoretical celestial systems because they are more likely. You need a specific tangential speed that matches your distance to the centre in order to reach circular motion - any higher or lower speed than that will distort the circular path into an ellipsis. For perfect circular motion to be achieved, the formula for centripetal acceleration must hold true:

$$a_c=\frac{v^2}r.$$

Answer (score 0):

Circle is a special kind of ellipse. You can get the circle equation with suitably changing the parameters of an ellipse. Now coming to your question ''why ellipse is favoured''. Because when you solve Newton's gravitational law you get equation of an ellipse. Now depending upon the mass of the planet and satelite(or planet or sun system) there is one specific distance (from planet or sun)where the energy of the satellite(or planet) becomes minimum . When the satelite travers with this fixed distance from the planet then only we can derive all the equations with circular orbit. In general the satelite is not bound to move in circle unless it has been placed to move in 'that' distance where it's energy is minimum. So you better analyse everything with respect to elliptic orbits and then you are always free to go to circular orbits from there.
All my sayings can be proved very easily on mathematical basis. I would suggest you to see any graduate textbook on Classical Mechanics and look for central forces chapter.